# Continuous integration of a tensor function using discrete density values

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, linear-algebra, interpolation, tensors

Hei,

I am wondering is it possible to implement continuous integration using `Integrate()` of a fourth order tensor with discrete density values.

```
Integrate[Integrate[C4 odf[theta, phi] Sin[theta], {theta, 0, Pi}], {phi, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

where `C4` is the fourth order tensor and `odf[theta, phi]` is presented as density values, i.e. `dens[i,j]`. The density values are given within the steps, for example 10 deg. I understand that to implement continuous integration the `interpolation` function (between the discrete steps) should also be involved somehow. The case is that I calculate `dens[i,j]` in `R`. `dens[i,j]` is not a simple array, but to produce `dens[i,j]` one should calculate the tensor series up to sixth order and I already have the script in `R`.